# asp.net textbox not updated from another task

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, gridview, textbox, task

I have a `GridView` and on its `SelectedIndexChanged` the code is fired:

```
protected void grdEntry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblAssignId.Text = grdEntry.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text == "&nbsp;" 
                       ? ""
                       : grdEntry.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    Ob.BranchId = Globals.BranchID;
    Ob.AssignId = lblAssignId.Text;
    DataSet dsMain = GetAssignDetails(Ob);
    if (dsMain.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        // some other code
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FillMemberShipAndBarCode(dsMain.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerCode"].ToString(), Ob.BranchId));
    }
}
```

and the code for filling membership id is

```
private void FillMemberShipAndBarCode(string customerCode, string branchId)
{
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText = "sp_customermaster",
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerCode", customerCode);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchId", branchId);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Flag", 18);
    var data = PrjClass.GetData(sqlCommand);
    txtMemberShip.Text = data.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MembershipId"].ToString();
    txtBarCode.Text = data.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Barcode"].ToString();    
}
```

It's working fine, but is is not updating any of the textboxes. Also, I checked in watch window, the values are returned as expected (`M-1213` and `634-98-4` ) and the code does reaches the point `txtMemberShip.Text = data.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MembershipId"].ToString();`
but the `txtMemberShip` just remains empty??? Can anyone tell me why is not updating the textboxes?

**UPDATE**

As per comments, here is the page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindDropDown();
        BindGrid();
        SetDefaultsInTextBoxes();
    }
}
```

And I don't have any code that waits on this task.

Comment: show me your `page_load` as well,are you using `page.ispostback` in `page_load` or not

Comment: Do you have code that waits for those tasks to be finished before the Render is executed?

Comment: ok what is the return type of `GetData` method and also check that `var data` is actually getting value from `procedure` or not.

Comment: ok tell me one thing that `txtBarCode.Text` is getting value or it also shows `empty`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FillMemberShipAndBarCode(dsMain.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerCode"].ToString(), Ob.BranchId));
```

What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

What is probably happening is your method `FillMemberShipAndBarCode` is probably running after ASP.NET has already sent the page back to the browser. Thus, essentially, no visible effect on the rendered HTML.

ASP.NET isn't a good place to do multi-threaded stuff.

Try just replacing the above with this:

```
FillMemberShipAndBarCode(dsMain.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerCode"].ToString(), Ob.BranchId);
```

Comment: yeah, probably that's what happening. I thought the something related too myself. It is being called after `Response` is sent to client. So, is there a way to do mulch-threading stuff in `asp.net`?

Comment: If you really want to do background stuff while a client (browser) is sat waiting for a response, there's no reason why you can't use TPL or other techniques - just block until your background stuff is completed, then react to it (by, for example, changing textbox values etc). So here, Task.Factory.StartNew() isn't void - it returns a Task. Keep a reference to that Task, and call its Wait() method. When that method returns, the Task will be complete.